# How to replace user defined function into SELECT clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sql-tuning

I have a performance issue in my query which takes more than 2 minutes to execute. Currently the main table f_trans has 3 million records.

I have indexed columns in where clause and join condition.

**Query :**

```
    SELECT f.no AS refno,  
               f.v_date AS v_date,  
               (SELECT fnbalance  
                                     (  
                                      f.acnt_code,  
                                      f.v_date,                                      
                                     )  
                    FROM DUAL) AS balance,  

        FROM   f_trans f JOIN glr_temp glr  
             ON f.acnt_code = glr.acnt_code  
             AND ftr.v_date >= '24-Aug-2014'  
             AND ftr.v_date <= '27-Aug-2014'  
               JOIN glm_gl_mast glm  
               ON f.acnt_code = glm.acnt_code  
             AND glr.acnt_code = glm.acnt_code;
```

**function:**

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE function fnbalance (  
p_glcode in   number,p_dtdate in   date,  
)  
   return number  
as  
   openbal   number;  
   dramt     number;  
   cramt     number;  

begin  

   dramt := 0;  
   cramt := 0;  
   balamt := 0;  
                  select nvl (sum (f.dr_amt), 0), nvl (sum (f.cr_amt), 0)  
                    into dramt, cramt  
                    from ftrans ftr  
                   where f.v_source <> 'FFT'    
                     and f.acnt_code = p_glcode  
                     and ftr.ftr_vou_date < p_dtdate;  

   select nvl(( dramt - cramt),0) into balamt from dual;  
   return balamt;  
end  


    Plan hash value: 1037159964

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                  |    53 |  1537 | 23581   (1)| 00:04:43 |
|   1 |  FAST DUAL             |                  |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |  HASH JOIN             |                  |    53 |  1537 | 23581   (1)| 00:04:43 |
|*  3 |   HASH JOIN            |                  |  7342 | 73420 |    12   (9)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| IND_GLR_ACC      |  5214 | 26070 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| GLM_AC_INDEX     |  7342 | 36710 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | F_TRANS |   181K|  3364K| 23568   (1)| 00:04:43 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Could help me to re organize the function into select clause?

Comment: Do the following, `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR <URQUERY>` and then `SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY)` .. Paste the output here..

Answer (score 1):

> AND ftr.v_date >= '24-Aug-2014'
>                AND ftr.v_date <= '27-Aug-2014'

First of all, this way of comparing a date with a literal is too bad. `v_date` being a `DATE` data type, you must compare it with dates and not literals. Use `TO_DATE` to convert a literal into date.

```
AND ftr.v_date >= TO_DATE('24-Aug-2014', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')
AND ftr.v_date <= TO_DATE('27-Aug-2014', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')
```

Say this to yourself, **never rely on implicit data conversions**. Always do it explicitly.

And please post the execution plan of the query to further see if the performance could be improved.

**Update**

See how to generate an execution plan in SQL*Plus

```
SQL> explain plan for select * from dual;

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 272002086

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**Copy paste the execution plan and post it here using code tags to preserve the formatting.**

Comment: Thanks lalit. I have modified but still the issue persists.

Comment: Post the execution plan as requested.

Comment: i couldn't add my plan as image :(

Comment: image is not required. See my update in answer to see how to post an execution plan.

Comment: i have posted the execution plan

Comment: That is not complete, include the predicate information. Paste the entire output of `dbms_xplan.display`

Comment: It is clearly visible that the `f_trans` table goes for a toss due to `full table scan`.  Is the column `acnt_code` indexed?